# Can I change the boot order of a machine via the SoftLayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Encountering an issue when trying to PXE boot a node where after the reboot to reload the node, it will try to use the NIC as a boot device again. Is there anyway to change the boot order so it will boot from disk via an API?

Answer (score 1):

Nope that is not possible currently via API.